# Python - Py2exe can't build .exe using the 'email' module

Tags: python, winapi, py2exe

py2exe does not work with the standard email module

Hello. I am trying to use py2exe for converting a script into an exe. The build process shows this:

---

The following modules appear to be missing

### ['email.Encoders', 'email.Generator', 'email.Iterators', 'email.MIMEBase', 'email.MIMEMultipart', 'email.MIMEText', 'email.Utils', 'email.base64MIME']

The executable does not work. The referenced modules are not included. I researched this on the Internet and I found out that py2exe has a problem with the Lazy import used in the standard lib email module. Unfortunately I have not succeeded in finding a workaround for this problem. Can anyone help?

Thank you,

P.S.
Imports in the script look like this:

Code: Select all
    import string,time,sys,os,smtplib
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
    from email import Encoders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to work with py2exe, bbfreeze works better, and I've tried it with the email module. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/0.95.4

Comment: Cheers for the link - I've been using py2exe previously, but will have to give this a try!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this question [how-to-package-twisted-program-with-py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169897/how-to-package-twisted-program-with-py2exe) it seems to be the same problem.

The answer given there is to explicitly include the modules on the command line to py2exe.

Answer (score 4):

What version of Python are you using?  If you are using 2.5 or 2.6, then you should be doing your import like:

```
import string,time,sys,os,smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
```

I'm pretty certain that py2exe's modulefinder can correctly find the email package if you use it correctly (i.e. use the above names in Python 2.5+, or use the old names in Python 2.4-).  Certainly the SpamBayes setup script does not need to explicitly include the email package, and it includes the email modules without problem.

The other answers are correct in that if you do need to specifically include a module, you use the "includes" option, either via the command-line, or passing them in when you call setup.

Comment: What is the alternate to add from "email.Utils import formatdate". i am facing issues on this when creating exe. Missing modules email.Utils

Answer (score 2):

Use the "includes" option.  See: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions

Comment: I tried, less errors, but still outputs : The following modules appear to be missing
['email.Encoders', 'email.Generator', 'email.Iterators', 'email.MIMEBase', 'email.MIMEMultipart', 'email.MIMEText', 'email.Utils', 'email.base64MIME']. bb-freeze is simpler to set up and worked "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by explicitly including missing modules in setup.py:

OLD setup.py:

```
setup(console = ['main.py'])
```

New setup.py:

```
setup(console = ['main.py'], 
      options={"py2exe":{"includes":["email.mime.multipart","email.mime.text"]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

while porting my app from py24 to 26 I had the same problem.

After reading http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs
if found finaly following solution:

### in my application.py:

```
import email
import email.mime.text
import email.mime.base
import email.mime.multipart
import email.iterators
import email.generator
import email.utils

try:    
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
except:    
    from email.mime import text as MIMEText
```

### in setup.py:

```
import modulefinder
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "base")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "multipart")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "nonmultipart")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "audio")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "image")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "message")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "application")
```

For py2exe to work with packages loaded during runtime, the main thing seems to be that u explicitly import the modules needed by your app somewhere in your app. 
And then give py2exe in setup.py with moudlefinder.AddPackagePath( ,  ) the hint, where to search for modules it couldn't find by std. introspection.
in the app

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem:
in setup.py edit

```
includes = ["email"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.  This works on my py2exe build. Just replace "project_name.py" with your main script.  The EXTRA_INCLUDES are packages that you need to include in your build like email package.  I this works with you also.

```
from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe, sys, os

    sys.argv.append('py2exe')

    EXTRA_INCLUDES = [
        "email.iterators", "email.generator", "email.utils", "email.base64mime", "email", "email.mime",
        "email.mime.multipart", "email.mime.text", "email.mime.base",
        "lxml.etree", "lxml._elementpath", "gzip"
    ]

    setup(
        options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, 'includes': EXTRA_INCLUDES,
                    'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe','MSVCR71.dll']}},
        console = [{'script': "project_name.py"}],
        zipfile = None,
    )
```

Comment: Works for me, which is a relief, since I never got bb-freeze to work at all.