# Python: error when is compiled with py2exe

Tags: python

I have a script in python that send an email

```
import email
import email.mime.application
...
msg = email.mime.Multipart.MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'test'
    msg['From'] = 'test@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'test@gmail.com'
body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""test""")

....
```

In python the script is running well, 
but after I compile it with py2exe I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "email\__init__.pyc", line 79, in __getattr__
ImportError: No module named multipart
```

In the py2exe compilation log I see this message

```
...
The following modules appear to be missing
['_scproxy', 'email.MIMEBase', 'email.MIMEMultipart', 'email.MIMEText']
....
```

Any idea how to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Just install the missing modules using pip or easy_install

Comment: I new to python, I installed pip, what  to do next? what is the syntax to install the missing modules

Comment: `pip install module`

Comment: where do I run that command ?

Comment: In the terminal: open cmd.exe and type it in

Answer (score 1):

If in python the script runs well, it seems that py2exe is not including all the needed modules.

Take a look at this question [Python - Py2exe can't build .exe using the 'email' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174170/python-py2exe-cant-build-exe-using-the-email-module)