# create executable for application using opencv?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, exe, py2exe

I have designed a small application in Python under Windows, that uses opencv.
I amm trying to create an executable so that anyone can install and use it, without having to install python/opencv/numpy . . .

I tried to use py2exe for this. It actually creates a .exe file, even though I have a warning during the build :

```
*** copy dlls ***
copying C:\Windows\system32\MSVFW32.dll -> 
...
The following modules appear to be missing
['cv2.cv']
```

When I try to run the .exe file using the command line, I see the message :

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

My setup.py file is pretty simple :

```
# creating executable here
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console=['facemovie.py'],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Any idea how I can solve this? 
This is the very first time I want to deploy, and I may be missing something.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks karlphilip, you put me on the tracks.

I wanted to avoid the "change my software utility" solution, so I stuck with py2exe.

Actually, opencv was correctly found, but the library itself has a numpy dependancy, which was not detected.

So my working solution is finally :
options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'includes': 'numpy' } },

The final executable is pretty big, but running smoothly.

I did not try on another computer, that does not have the software installed though, so there might be surprises to come.

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: You asked this question 4 years ago. I'm curious, did you try on another computer without open cv installed? I'm curious to know if it works in that case.

Comment: It's been a long time so I won't remember for sure but I am pretty confident I did try this on PCs without OpenCV on them. :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169913/176769), **py2exe** is not detecting that this module is needed inside the ZIP archive. I don't know the right syntax so you'll have to check the docs, but you could try:

```
python setup.py py2exe -p cv2
```

Or you could try to tweak `setup.py` to the following:

```
options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'packages': 'cv2' } },
```

And if you are willing to try something completely different, take a look at [**bbfreeze**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/):

> create standalone executables from python scripts

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). I used it for a project of mine that referenced both pycrypto and twisted and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. I resolved it by moving the image file to the folder where the executable is created.This worked for both py2exe and pyinstaller.